# Split beamer notes across multiple notes pages

Tags: beamer, page-breaking, notes

I've only recently discovered the `notes` mode for [`beamer`](http://ctan.org/pkg/beamer), and I'm trying to build a presentation with notes containing my speech.  However, my speech is quite large, and is causing note page overflows.

I'm thus looking for something akin to the `\allowframebreaks` flag to the `frame` environment.  Is there something that performs this function?

Comment: Did you considered bemaerarticle?

Comment: It may be worth having another crack at Beamer article. I had little success so I'll try another tutorial on it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The closest thing I know is frame overlays, in Beamer a frame can have several overlays (when you use `\pause`), and you can have different notes for each overlay.

Now this is not exactly what you are asking for. Maybe you can still use this as a workaround, if there's some way to generate "invisible" overlays just for the purpose of adding more notes pages. (Just using pause with no content after it will produce duplicated slides, I guess.)

On the other hand, if you are using this to show the regular slide in one screen and the notes slide in another, what you want is *exactly* to add several `\pause`s to have as many overlays as you want, and split your notes through the overlays, so it will still show the same slide when showing the next notes slide.

Like this:

```
\documentclass[ignorenonframetext,pdfusetitle,17pt]{beamer}
\setbeameroption{show notes}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\title{Twitter Architecture}
\author{SA Group 2\\2010 Fall}

\begin{document}
\mode<all>
\begin{frame}{Peaks}
  \textbf{Variable} request rate 
  \pause

  ``\textbf{Constant}'' resources

  \note<2>{Explain the quotes: They can add more machines, but doing
    so as a reaction to rate change is not the same thing. From the
    point of view of random rate changes, resources are constant.}

  \pause

  \textbf{Spread} load over time
  \pause

  How? \textbf{Message Queues}
  \pause
  \note<4>{Twitter controls request rate}
  \pause
  \note<5>{\texttt{(open (get-door 'podbay))}\\
    \texttt{NIL}\\\texttt{(open (get-door 'podbay))}\\
    \texttt{NIL}\\\texttt{(open (get-door 'podbay))}\\
    \texttt{NIL}\\\texttt{(open (get-door 'podbay))}\\
    \texttt{NIL}\\\texttt{(open (get-door 'podbay))}\\
    \texttt{NIL}\\\texttt{(open (get-door 'podbay))}}
  \note<6>{``You can't fight in here!'' -- Merkin Muffley}
\end{frame}
\mode*
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Initially, I thought this wasn't what I was looking for, but substituting all my `\note`'s for `\note<+>`'s, I got the desired effect.  Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

I've just found another solution.

```
\begin{frame}{Slide}
\Huge This is slide
\end{frame}

\note{\Huge Note 1}
\newpage
\note{\Huge Note 2}
```

Comment: Nice, thanks, though it did require me to move my note out of the frame, which the docs don’t recommend.

Comment: Works wonderfully :)

Comment: What do you mean with moving out of the frame? The note is after the frame always and the compiler detects the frame it belongs to..no?

Comment: @RalfB Flash Sheridan was correct.  Please see the chosen answer (above) for an example of what is meant by the note being "in the frame."

Comment: Works well for my purposes...