# beamer shrink note pages

Tags: beamer

`Beamer`s `shrink` is *evil*, but I want to use it on my `notes`-pages. (As a reminder: `shrink` automatically reduces the font-size so that all text fits on a slide). I use `\note` as a separate command after each frame (I prefer that to inline notes). Sometimes there is too much text to fit on the `notes`-page. Is there a way to `shrink` the text on the notes-page?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}
\setbeameroption{show only notes}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{A frame}
With not so much text
\end{frame}

\note{\begin{itemize}
\item Instead,
\item I
\item Have
\item A
\item Lot
\item I
\item Want
\item To
\item Say
\item And
\item Explain
\end{itemize}
}
\end{document}
```

Related question:

- [Split beamer notes across multiple notes pages](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35444/split-beamer-notes-across-multiple-notes-pages) has the same problem, but a different approach, and uses inline `\note`s.

If there is no way to do this, plan B may be to reduce the font size for *all* `\note`-pages. But not for the slides themselves!

Comment: If this is the particular example only related to items then replacing the `\note{\begin{itemize}
` line with `\note{\begin{itemize}\addtolength{\itemsep}{-0.5\baselineskip}` shrinks it. But can't say I understood what your goal is. Put two identical frames if you like to have extra note space without incrementing the page number. It would be virtually invisible. I think it's much better than squeezing the efficiency on one page.

Comment: Some of my notes have more text than others. For most of my notes, all the text fits with `normalsize`, some need `small` for all to fit, some need `footprintsize`, etc. In reality I have a frame consisting of many slides; how would putting two identical frames (you mean `\againframe`?) be virtually invisible? I don't understand.

Comment: What I mean is that if you have limited space for notes for each slide, then repeating the same slide would give you extra space and `\againframe` is one such option such that you can fill up the extra portion of the notes to that new space. It is of course a suggestion but seems natural to me although I might have misunderstood the whole problem.

Comment: The notes are not on the slide. I generate a completely different document with `\beameroption{show only notes}` that I use when I practice the presentation. I have one note page for each frame. This is nothing that the audience will see, so `\againframe` seems strange for me to use. It`s only for myself and only while practicing.

Comment: [Here is my example](http://pastebin.com/ePfMJ08c) hopefully displaying my way of thinking...

Comment: Yes, but then the frame is displayed twice. I realise that it works, but it's not really comfortable if I have overlay specifications, so I still need to tweak things by hand for different frames/note-pages. The point of my question is to find out an automatic way, so I don't have to tweak individual frames by hand.

Comment: You are right. I will try to see if `\note` command allows such access.

Comment: A note page isn't implemented as a normal `beamer` frame, but typeset using its own code which can be found in [`beamerbasenotes.sty`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/base/beamerbasenotes.sty) (cf. `\beamer@outsideframenote`, ll. 59-103). Therefore, using normal frame options like `shrink` or `allowframebreaks` isn't possible.

Comment: @diabonas Could you make your comment into an answer?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A note page isn't implemented as a normal `beamer` frame, but typeset using its own code which can be found in [beamerbasenotes.sty](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/base/beamerbasenotes.sty) (cf. `\beamer@outsideframenote`, ll. 59-103). Therefore, using normal frame options like `shrink` or `allowframebreaks` isn't possible.

Answer (score 4):

I encountered the same issue. I got around it by using the Beamer command `\AtBeginNote{\scriptsize}`. (See section 19.2 of [the Beamer documentation.](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/beamer?lang=en)) You can of course use any [font size](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Fonts#Sizing_text) you wish. Be sure to use this command outside of the `frame` environment.

If you need to or want to, you can undo this by issuing the empty `\AtBeginNote{}` command.

Comment: You can, if you wish, change the font size for just one note, if you specify the font size within said "note" command's braces.