# How to sync Beamer notes and pause commands?

Tags: beamer, notes, pause

I want to use `\pause` in my lecture notes, and I want a notes-only version that uncovers different notes before each pause. I thought of using the `\note<.>{"my note"}` syntax, because my understanding of '.' is that it refers to the current `beamerpauses` counter. But when I do this, as in this example, I don't get the desired effect. In fact I don't get all the notes:

```
\documentclass[t, 14pt]{beamer}
\setbeameroption{show only notes} 

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}
\item First things first
\note[item]<.>{Say ``first things first''}
\pause
\item Second things second
\note[item]<.>{Say ``second things second''}
\pause
\item Third things third
\note[item]<.>{Say nothing...}
\pause
\item 4th thing
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

This results in:

[image]

Notice the first note ('Say "first thing first"') is not even present. The second note exists before the second bullet point.

I looked into dropping the `\pause` command and using `\note<+>` commands, as suggested in a  comment to [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/35496/9305), but it only leads to pauses in my notes and not on the slides.

**How do I have one note per pause command? How do I get them to pause in both the presentation and the notes mode?**

I should also point out that if I use `\note<1>{...}` and `\note<2>{...}` I *do* get the desired effect. I just don't want to keep track of how many `\pause` and overlay commands I've made, so I guess I should ask

**How do you *easily* have one note per pause command?**

Answer (score 4):

Instead of `\pause`, you could use the overlay specification for `itemize`:

```
\documentclass[t, 14pt]{beamer}
\setbeameroption{show only notes} 

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}[<+->]
\item First things first
\note<.>[item]{Say ``first things first''}
\item Second things second
\note<.>[item]{Say ``second things second''}
\item Third things third
\note<.>[item]{Say nothing...}
\item 4th thing
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This appears to be a good solution. It works and gives the desired effect. And I guess I would use `\item<.->` if I wanted to have more than one bullet/number revealed at once. Do you know why your approach works and `\pause` doesn't?

Comment: @Yann no, I don't know the *real* reason, but I've encountered other situations in which `\pause` seems to interact in unexpected ways with other overlay specifications.